# Asp.net mvc client side validation - show errors in the same div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, client-side-validation

How do I list all generated errors in the same div?

Something like this:

```
<div id="errors">
  <ul>
    <li>Email is invalid</li>
    <li>Firstname is required</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
<%=Html.ValidationSummary()%>
```

There is a section about it in this article: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/performing-simple-validation-cs

Comment: Everything works with server-side validation, but not client-side.

Comment: Did you call Html.EnableClientValidation(); and added appropriate javascript?  See section entitled Making It Work In The Client in http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx

Comment: I've followed the quide and tried with both jquery scripts and the pure ms validation scripts. I'm calling EnableClientValidation in my view.

Comment: For Html.ValidationSummary to work for client side validation, you must put it inside the form.